# Google Cloud SQL Timed Out from external server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, ip, google-cloud-sql

I just connect the Google Cloud SQL using authorized network. If i add my website ip address in authorized network the connection was timed out. But if i add following CIDR (0.0.0.0/0) range and also my local ip address its working fine . That means written code was not a problem. Then what is the problem. I don't have any idea. Please help me. Thank you.

I try to connect using following code

```
$server = "**.***.**.**";
$user = "databaseUser";
$pass = "databasePassword";
$db = "dbname";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Unable to connect. Error: ".$conn->connect_error;
    $conn = null;
}
```

The above code is working if i add CIDR range to 0.0.0.0/0. But its not working if add my website ip address.